# Can Not create datetime in tfileinputdelimited in talend

Tags: datetime, talend

I can not datetime in schema of tfileinputdelimited. I create date pattern "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" then input data is 2021/02/16 18:01:02.222. And then I get error
Couldn't parse value for column 'column name' in 'row1', value is '2021/01/16 17:01:02.222'. Details: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unparseable date: "2021/01/16 17:01:02.222"

Please help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
Your input data is :  "2021/01/16 17:01:02.222"
You mixed slashes and hyphens.